# APEX Trigger- Internal SOAP API callout error

Tags: soap-api

1. I am trying to create a SkillUser through the soap api because dml operations are not allowed but keep getting the following error below.
2. we plan on placing this code future call to send multiple records in a single call when a user is updated. The soap api call sounds like it would be the best design option since we can only send 1 record at a time through the rest api. if anyone has a better idea that would be great. thank you!

***The prefix "soapenv" for element "soapenv:Header" is not bound.***

```
Http h = new Http(); 
HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
String sfdcBaseURL = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
System.debug('Base URL: ' + sfdcBaseURL ); 
String url = sfdcBaseURL+'/services/Soap/u/33.0';
System.debug(url);
req2.setEndpoint(url);
req2.setHeader('content-type', 'text/xml'); 
req2.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
req2.setMethod('POST');
String xml2= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
 +'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">' +
 '<soapenv:Header>'+
 '<urn:SessionHeader>'+
  '<urn:sessionId>'+ UserInfo.getSession() +'</urn:sessionId>'+
 '</urn:SessionHeader>'+
    '</soap:Header>' +
 '</soapenv:Header>'+
'<soapenv:Body>'+
     '<urn:create>'+
        '<urn:sObjects xsi:type="SkillUser">'+
           '<UserId>'+ '005j00000045gtyuj' + '</UserId>'+
           '<SkillId>' + '005j000000Crtrtrr' + '</SkillId>'+
        '</urn:sObjects>'+
     '</urn:create>'+
  '</soapenv:Body>'+
  '</soapenv:Envelope>';
req2.setBody(xml2);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req2);
String output = res.getBody();
System.debug('Body contains:' +output);
```

Comment: with Summer 15, u can get into pilot for rest api enhancements (batch & tree modes) which allows multiple record handling http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_api_rest.htm

Answer (score 1):

The error:

> The prefix "soapenv" for element "soapenv:Header" is not bound.

is most likely from your XML SOAP body.

The first line of your XML has

```
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
    xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
```

Notice how you have `xmlns:soap` namespace, but no `xmlns:soapenv` namespace.

So, you get the error when you try and reference the undefined soapenv namespace with `'<soapenv:Header>'+`...

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `soap:Envelope` with `soapenv:Envelope`should do the trick.

Comment: I did that and now I am getting  this error: